# Clicking a button using xpath

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I am trying to click this button:

```
        <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
            <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
                <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
                    <span class="ui-button-text">Create</span>
                </button>
               <button aria-disabled="false" role="button" class="ui-button ui-widget    ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button">

               <span class="ui-button-text">Close</span>
               </button>
               </div>
```

I want to do so using xpath. Here is my code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[22]/div[3]/div/button[1]")
```

I have also tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[22]/div[3]/div/button[1]")
```

I keep getting the error **unable to locate element**. Should I try a different locator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the CSS is the same, you could get all buttons, get text and see if it is what you want and click on it. I do not know `python` so pardon my syntax mistakes.

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button")

for button in buttons:
  if button.text.strip() == "Create":
    button.click()
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues that could cause that problem.  Without the full source of that page it's impossible to tell which is causing it.  A few examples:

- Is the button being loaded dynamically?  If so, perhaps Selenium is attempting to access it before it's actually on the page.  You may have to wait until the element is loaded.
- Is the button inside of an iframe?  In this case, you will need to switch to the correct fame using driver.switch_to_frame().  See [this page](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames) for more information on how to switch frames.
- Are you loading in other elements dynamically?  As the button appears to be in div 22, that seems possible.  This could change the XPath of the button when these elements are loaded.

In the end, if the XPath is correct, the element is loaded, and you're looking at the right frame, it should be able to find the element.  One solution, if you're in a position to be editing the page source, is to add an id attribute to the button you are trying to click.  It would then be trivial to locate the element by its ID.  You can find documentation for that [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html#locating-by-id).  Please note that the ID must be unique in order to ensure you find the correct button.  This would also solve the problem of other elements being loaded in dynamically.

Comment: Thank You. It was inside of an Iframe

Comment: Yep, it was iframe took 2 hours to figure out...

Answer (score 1):

Try

To click `Close` button-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='ui-button ui-widget    ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only']/following-sibling::span[@class='ui-button-text' and contains(text(),'Close')]").click()
```

Comment: that would potentially find a lot of buttons

Comment: Can you assure me that there is only one `div` with class name `ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix` or share more html source-or better url

Comment: ok I added the ending part of the code. There are 2 buttons that seem to have the same tags but are named differently. "Create","Close"